Invalid object name 'dbo.uspEnvelopeBudgetTransactionsBalanceQuery' error from a Sql Server stored procedure
When I Execute the following, I get the error.
ALTER PROCEDURE \[dbo\].\[uspEnvelopeBudgetTransactionsBalanceQuery2\]

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;  SELECT * , (SELECT SUM(T2.[SumOfAmount]) FROM dbo.uspEnvelopeBudgetTransactionsBalanceQuery AS T2 WHERE T2.[PayDate] <= T1.[PayDate]) AS Balance FROM dbo.uspEnvelopeBudgetTransactionsBalanceQuery AS T1;
I tried to get it to run by delete dbo. and usp from EnvelopeBudgetTransactionsQuery.I tried dropping it and recreating it.
What is want is a running total of SumOfAmount in by PayDate. I am migrating the backend of an Access database to Sql Server and I am new to Sql Server.
